# Flyway is not able to find migrations in classpath only if I run application after assembling it with jlink

Tags: java, gradle, flyway, java-platform-module-system, jlink

I am using Gradle's [badass-jlink-plugin](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin) in order to assembly java, my JavaFX application and its dependencies into one artifact - custom runtime - so I can share only `zip` file.

I created a *MWE* for my problem which is available here: https://github.com/VictorAtPL/jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem

After executing `prepareModulesDir` task of this plugin, in `build/jlinkbase/jlinkjars` there are following `jar`s:

1. `jar`s with dependencies which were modular (contains `module-info.class` from the beginning; `javafx-base-12.0.1-linux.jar`, `derby-10.15.1.3.jar`, etc.),
2. catch-all `jar` dependency which contains all files of dependencies which weren't modular (authors didn't make them modular by, among others, adding `module-info.java` file; `jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem.merged.module-0.1.0-alpha.jar`),
3. `jar`s which are proxies to the *catch-all* `jar` file (by using `require transitive` clause in `module-info.java`; `flyway-core-6.1.4.jar`),
4. `jar` with classes and resources of application's main module (`jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem-0.1.0-alpha.jar`).

More about how `badass-jlink-plugin` works can be found in docs here: https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/#_how_it_works

The main module of application contains resources (`.sql` files in `src/main/resources/db/migration`) and classes (`.java` files in `src/main/java/db/migration`) which are migrations for [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) library.

If I create custom runtime images using `jlink` task (`./jlink.sh` script) and run application using system-installed java (`run_system_java.sh`, which executes `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/java --module-path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/jmods/:./build/jlinkbase/jlinkjars --module jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem/app.Main`) then *Flyway* works correctly (finds and applies both migrations).

If I run application using custom created runtime (`./run_assembled_java.sh`, which executes `./build/image/bin/java -m jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem/app.Main`) I got following warning:

```
Jan 24, 2020 8:22:38 PM org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner findResourceNames
WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration
```

So during execution of `jlink` by `badass-jlink-plugin` something gets broken, because `db/migration` cannot be found after creating the `modules` file for custom runtime.

This is a command executed by `jlink` task:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/jlink -v --compress 2 --no-header-files --no-man-pages --module-path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/jmods/:/home/piotr/IdeaProjects/jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem/build/jlinkbase/jlinkjars --add-modules jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem --output /home/piotr/IdeaProjects/jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem/build/image
```

I also attach the result of `gradle jlink` and `jimage list build/image/lib/modules`: https://gist.github.com/VictorAtPL/69e50e1738429548d1e6d8070e37b062

I think the main reason why it acts like this is that [this](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/scanner/classpath/ClassPathScanner.java#L249) line in `ClassPathScanner.java` of *Flyway* acts differently when running with different javas (system-installed and custom runtime created by jlink).

In the first scenario it finds a URL: `jar:file:///home/piotr/IdeaProjects/jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem/build/jlinkbase/jlinkjars/jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem-0.1.0-alpha.jar!/db/migration/`, in the second - it doesn't (`classLoader.getResources("db/migration").nextElement()` throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException`; but `classLoader.getResources("db/migration/V1__Initial_version.sql").nextElement()` works).

I am providing screenshots for second scenario (with custom java runtime):
[image: getResources on file]
[image: getResources on directory]

I believe there is some issue with classLoader when working with `modules` from java custom runtime. Why cannot I look for directories when using `jrt` based urls?

I would appreciate someone guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it behaves differently in these two scenarios, but Flyway's ClassPathScanner will find the resources if you place them on the classpath.
To do this, you can copy the resources in a subdirectory of your image and add this subdirectory to the classpath:

```
tasks.jlink {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'src/main/resources'
            into "$imageDir/bin/data"
        }
    }
}

jlink {
    ...
    launcher {
        ...
        jvmArgs = ['-cp', '$DIR/data/']
    }
}
```

I submitted the above changes as a pull request to your MWE: https://github.com/VictorAtPL/jlink_badass_flyway_classpath_problem/pull/1

Comment: Thank you. I think it fixes the problem, but partially. The main question is why Jigsaw acts differently. I won't accept this answer by now, maybe someone will add his two cents.